# Binding в vue. Проблема обновления значения в поле

Tags: javascript, vue.js, binding, vuex, vuetify

Имеется форма в которой задаём поле страны используется `<Autocomplete>`

```
    <div class="col-4 pa-0 relative">
       <Autocomplete
          v-model="new_queue.country_id"
          :items="countries"
          text="Страна"
          :rules="[rules.required]"
          :readonly="readonlyField"
       />
    </div>
```

в этой же форме компонент таблица с данными в которых отображается значение данного поля, для связи используется `.sync`

```
<div class="col-12 pa-0 mb-4">
  <ListVehiclesTable
     ref="ListVehiclesTable"
     :new-queue.sync="new_queue"
     @editQueuecar="editQueuecar"
     @deleteQueuecar="deleteQueuecar"
     :get-status="getStatus"
   />
</div>
```

при изменении страны селектором всё окей, но если стереть поле, кликнуть в стороне и потом опять выбрать страну она уже не обновляется в таблице, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Что такое `new_queue`?

Comment: А покажите полный код, мне кажется, что у вас вообще отрабатывает изменение только один раз.

Comment: @Oleksandr объект с информацией со всей формы

Comment: @doox911 Отрабатывает не один раз, после воспроизведения бага выбираешь другой вариант в селекторе и всё снова работает

Comment: Вы можете привести код двух компонентов?